# Разворачивание таблиц

Tags: sql, interbase

Есть три таблицы

- `main` (`id`, `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, ...)
- `detail` (`id`, `main_id`)
- `sub_detail` (`id`, `param`, `val`)

Связь `main` -> `detail` один ко многим, `detail` -> `sub_detail` один к одному (по полям `id`)

На выходе нужно получить таблицу с полями

`main_id`, `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `value1`, `value2`, `value3`

где `valueN` это значение поля `val` из таблицы `sub_detail` для записи с `param = N`. Не все `valueN` могут присутствовать в базе.

Базовый запрос выглядит так

```
SELECT
  m.id AS main_id,
  m.f1,
  m.f2,
  m.f3,
  s1.val AS value1,
  s2.val AS value2,
  s3.val AS value3
FROM
  main m
  LEFT JOIN detail d ON (
    d.main_id = m.id
  )
  LEFT JOIN sub_detail s1 ON (
    s1.id = d.id AND
    s1.param = 1
  )
  LEFT JOIN sub_detail s2 ON (
    s2.id = d.id AND
    s2.param = 2
  )
  LEFT JOIN sub_detail s3 ON (
    s3.id = d.id AND
    s3.param = 3
  )
WHERE
  m.id = 1;
```

Но он вместо одной записи возвращает столько записей, сколько есть дочерних записей в `detail`.

Поставить группировку по `main.id` и вытаскивать `MAX(s.val)` я не могу, т.к. в запросе есть еще поля `f1`, `f2`

Есть вариант на основании `detail` и `sub_detail` построить view

```
CREATE VIEW vw_detail (
  main_id,
  param,
  val
) AS
SELECT
  d.main_id,
  s.param,
  s.val
FROM
  detail d
  JOIN sub_detail s ON (
    d.id = s.id
  )
```

и вызывать ее в основном запросе

```
SELECT
  m.id AS main_id,
  m.f1,
  m.f2,
  m.f3,
  s1.val AS value1,
  s2.val AS value2,
  s3.val AS value3
FROM
  main m
  LEFT JOIN vw_detail s1 ON (
    s1.main_id = m.id AND
    s1.param = 1
  )
  LEFT JOIN vw_detail s2 ON (
    s2.main_id = m.id AND
    s2.param = 2
  )
  LEFT JOIN vw_detail s3 ON (
    s3.main_id = m.id AND
    s3.param = 3
  )
WHERE
  m.id = 1;
```

но в Interbase есть старый баг из-за которого при вызове `LEFT JOIN view` начинают игнорироваться индексы и происходит полное сканирование таблицы. А писать `JOIN vw_detail` нельзя, потому что некоторые (или даже все) параметры могут отсутствовать.

Пробовал писать так

```
CREATE VIEW vw_values (
  main_id,
  value1,
  value2,
  value3
) AS
SELECT
  m.id,
  MAX(s1.val),
  MAX(s2.val),
  MAX(s3.val),
FROM
  main m
  LEFT JOIN detail d ON (
    d.main_id = m.id
  )
  LEFT JOIN sub_detail s1 ON (
    s1.id = d.id AND
    s1.param = 1
  )
  LEFT JOIN sub_detail s2 ON (
    s2.id = d.id AND
    s2.param = 2
  )
  LEFT JOIN sub_detail s3 ON (
    s3.id = d.id AND
    s3.param = 3
  )
GROUP BY
  m.id;
```

и потом в основном запросе

```
SELECT
  m.id AS main_id,
  m.f1,
  m.f2,
  m.f3,
  v.value1,
  v.value2,
  v.value3
FROM
  main m
  JOIN vw_values v ON (
    v.main_id = m.id
  )
WHERE
  m.id = 1;
```

но тогда вначале идет построение VIEW с группировкой, а потом накладывание условия `v.main_id = m.id`. План получается дикий.

Вариант заменить `vw_values` селективной процедурой тоже не подходит. Т.к. основной запрос выполняется в другой view, а синтаксис Interbase не позволяет внутри view использовать процедуры

P.S. Вариант перейти на Firebird не предлагать

Ссылка на [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=3be4f4b36ec87de34857e098e3f631df).

Comment: Создайте fiddle с сочетаниями значений, способными вызвать косяки (описанные в вопросе), и без таковых.

Comment: @Akina есть движок на Interbase? Потому, что для Firebird все не так печально

Comment: Да какая разница? любой, чем ближе к IB, тем лучше, конечно, но если какие конструкции недопустимы - подрихтуем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Денормализовал таблицу `detail` и скопировал туда поле `param`. После чего запрос переписался в такой вид

```
SELECT
  m.id AS main_id,
  m.f1,
  m.f2,
  m.f3,
  s1.val AS value1,
  s2.val AS value2,
  s3.val AS value3
FROM
  main m
  LEFT JOIN detail d1 ON (
    d1.main_id = m.id AND
    d1.param = 1
  )
  LEFT JOIN sub_detail s1 ON (
    s1.id = d1.id
  )
  LEFT JOIN detail d2 ON (
    d2.main_id = m.id AND
    d2.param = 2
  )
  LEFT JOIN sub_detail s2 ON (
    s2.id = d2.id
  )
  LEFT JOIN detail d3 ON (
    d3.main_id = m.id AND
    d3.param = 3
  )
  LEFT JOIN sub_detail s3 ON (
    s3.id = d3.id
  )
WHERE
  m.id = 1;
```

Если кто подскажет решение без денормализации - буду рад

---

**Update**

Причем поля `detail.main_id` и `detail.param` должны входить в общий индекс. Если завести два отдельных, то хоть и план строится с использованием индексов, но выполнение очень долгое

Answer (score 3):

```sql
SELECT
  m.id AS main_id,
  m.f1,
  m.f2,
  m.f3,
  MAX(s1.val) AS value1,
  MAX(s2.val) AS value2,
  MAX(s3.val) AS value3
FROM
  main m
  LEFT JOIN detail d ON (
    d.main_id = m.id
  )
  LEFT JOIN sub_detail s1 ON (
    s1.id = d.id AND
    s1.param = 1
  )
  LEFT JOIN sub_detail s2 ON (
    s2.id = d.id AND
    s2.param = 2
  )
  LEFT JOIN sub_detail s3 ON (
    s3.id = d.id AND
    s3.param = 3
  )
WHERE
  m.id = 1
GROUP BY   m.id,
           m.f1,
           m.f2,
           m.f3
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=9e02f3310820b5907405a899afdca3da)

Comment: А если дополнительных полей не три, а 20, то все их последовательно перечислять в `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Да, конечно, а как иначе? даже странно видеть такой вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос скорее был риторическим. Ладно, проблему, описанную в вопросе, ответ решает, но мою, к сожалению нет. В запросе есть вычисляемые поля с CASE и от `CASE MAX()` Interbase возвращает ошибку. И при формировании VIEW с этим запросом и последующим запросом `SELECT * FROM vw_test WHERE id = 1` я получаю FULL SCAN по master

Comment: [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=6b207f1ad865dbf668c3eb126f325818)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov *я получаю FULL SCAN по master* master - та, что main, что ли? *В запросе есть вычисляемые поля с CASE* Ну в fiddle кейсов нет. Где они в реальном-то запросе?

Comment: По `main`. Фиг с ним с CASE. Это очередной баг интербейса и ничего ты с ним не сделаешь. От FULL SCAN как уйти?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Что-то не получается на fiddle получить план запроса - на `set plan on;` выдаётся *Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 1, column 5 plan*

Comment: А еще в Firebird может быть другая картина. Ладно, ответу +1, но не "верный". Очень глючная СУБД и с этим приходится жить